# Trying to prove a local minimum, calculus 2

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

I'm asked to prove that the function
$$
F(x)=\int_{0.5}^{x} e^{t^2}\cdot(t^2-1) \,dt\
$$

has a local minimum at $x=1$.

I've tried defining a new function, $f$ such that $f(x)=e^{x^2}\cdot(x^2-1)$, and then applying $x=1$,

then claiming that $f(x)$ is derivative of $F(x)$,therefor $f(1)=0$ and showing that for some $x_0<1 \rightarrow f(x_0)<0$

and for another $x_1>1 \rightarrow f(x_1)>0$ which confirms that $x=1$ is local minimum for $F(x)$.

Only to realize that $t$ is substitute for something, and therefor I cannot claim $t=x$.

I'm stuck in my thoughts, any direction/idea of what I'm trying/needed to prove would be really helpful.

Cheers!

Comment: The local minimum of the integral occurs when the area added to the function is no longer negative: that is to say there is a zero there.

Comment: Your solution seems correct to me. Where did you claim that $t=x$?

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski I did not mention anywhere that $t=x$, only had the idea to define a function where instead of $t$ i'm using $x$ and calling it $F(x)$'s derivative. Yet I have no information regarding $t$ and what it stands for, compared to $x$ which is the variable which $F , f$ should be based upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is essentially correct. One small point to consider is that you say that "$f(x)$ is the derivative of $F(x)$ therefore $f(1)=0$". This should be phrased more carefully: you *want* to show that $x=1$ is a local minimum, it is not that which you already *know*. So in order to show that $x=1$ is a critical point, you have to show that $f(1)=0$, which is indeed true. To show that it is a local minimum you can differentiate again:
$$f'(x)=e^{x^2}\cdot 2x + e^{x^2}2x(x^2-1)$$
therefore  $F''(1)=f'(1)>0$ which shows that $x=1$ is a local minimum (alternatively, the way you did it by analysing $f(x)$ for $x>1$ and $x<1$ separately is just fine as well).

You never substituted $t=x$. Recall that the fundamental theorem of calculus says that $F'(x)=f(x)$. The $t$ inside the definition of $F(x)$ is a dummy variable, the real variable is $x$ in both $F(x)$ and $f(x)$. To expand on this point:

In the definition of $F(x)=\int_{0.5}^x e^{t^2}\cdot (t^2-1)\,dt$, which is the variable of the function $F(x)$, is it $x$ or $t$? Surely it is $x$, for $t$ is but an internal dummy variable. Consider this analog: let $a(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n b(k)$. Which is the variable, $n$ or $k$? Surely it is $n$, for $k$ is but the internal variable for summation; it does not exist outside the summation, it only exists to perform the summation. We could have just as well written the summation without the variable $k$, say $b(1)+b(2)+\ldots+b(n)$. In the very same way in $F(x)$ the variable is $x$; it denotes the upper bound of integration. The variable $t$ is an internal variable which does not exist outside the integral. For this reason the fundamental theorem of calculus says that $F'(x)=f(x)$, rather than $F'(x)=f(t)$, which would not make sense, as $t$ would be a free variable on the right hand side but it does not exist as a free variable on the left hand side (as it exists only inside the definition of the integral).

Comment: What bothers me is that the exercise defined $F(x)$ using the integral that is using $t,dt$ which is a common substitution variable.  so I assumed that I cannot directly define $f(x)$ using $x$'s instead of $t$'s... now I'm actually confused.

Comment: @Aish The expression $\int_0^x f(t) \mathrm dt$ does not contain the variable $t$ as a free variable. You could also write $I_{[0,x]}(f)$, for example.

Comment: @Aishgadol I have added some more clarification regarding this point. Does this make sense now?

Comment: It does make sense, yet I feel this is somewhat unclear to me.
What if (for example) $t=x^2-4$? or some sort of substitution? doesnt that change the definition of $F(x)$? Even though I understand the sum example, I dont seem to accept the fact that this $t$ is replaceable by $x$, it feels abit "cheating-ish" 
Nonetheless, other comments confirmed that my method of solving is correct and is the right way to go in this exercise, I will solve it using advice and information I acquired here.
Thank you for your assistance!
I'll reread it a few times, maybe something will sink in :)

Comment: @Aishgadol If you make make a substitution inside the integral then the limits of integration will change correspondingly. If we substitute we shouldn't use $x$ because it already appears in the limits of integration, so to avoid confusion use $u$. Say you substitute $u=t^2-4$. Then $\int_{0.5}^x f(t)\,dt$ becomes $\int_{-3.75}^{x^2-4} g(u)\,du$ where $g(u)$ is determined by the substitution rule. The point is that the limits of integration changed, as they usually do when performing a substitution on definite integrals. Note that the original $t$ inside $F(x)$ does not denote substitution.

Answer (score 0):

We may use libenitz rule for computing f'(x) and then we can calculate f"(x) very easily.
https://ibb.co/1n6B1fk
https://ibb.co/YZC71B8

Hope it helps !

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Ok sir.I will definitely learn to type in MathJax .